# Dynamic JQuery CSS corner case

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I dynamically add a CSS class to a div containing a flash message with this line of code:

```
$("div#flash_notice").toggleClass('success');
```

The javascript file is in my `micropost` view so that it is executed when I add a post. All is well except for when I add two posts without refreshing the page, because then the flash message loses it's style when it toggles back to remove the class. How can I get around this?

Comment: That depends on what you want it to do. Do you want the `success` class to just stay on? Do you want to somehow flash/blink\animate the `flash_notice` so that the user knows the toggle applied to their latest post? Do you want it to change to a different class? Also, since you are referencing an element by id, there's no need to use the tag name prefix. (`#flash_notice` instead of `div#flash_notice`)

Comment: First of all, it's wrong to have two elements with the same id. You should use classes for that. I've seen browsers break the functionality if that happens.

Comment: @Rfvgyhn I initially did not want to do animation, but I'm curious what the code would need to be to have the message fade out after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use toggle class. use addClass and it will add the class only if it does not have it:

```
$("div#flash_notice").addClass('success');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class only to elements that do not already have the class:

```
$("div#flash_notice").not('.success').addClass('success');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.addClass` method instead like others have mentioned. In repsonse to your comment about animating, you could do something like this:

```
var flashNoticeTimeout;
var fadeOutDelay = 1000;

function onPostAdded() {
    var $flashNotice = $("#flash_notice");    // Get flash_notice element
    $flashNotice.show().addClass("success");  // Show the flash element and then add the 'success' class.
                                              // Need to use .show because the .fadeOut later on will have hidden this element

    clearTimeout(flashNoticeTimeout);         // Clear any previous timeouts. If the user button adds a post, then adds another post before the element has faded out, this will clear the last timeout so the element isn't hidden before 'fadeOutDelay`

    flashNoticeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {  // Trigger this anon function after 'fadeOutDelay' milliseconds (1000 milliseconds = 1 second)
        $flashNotice.fadeOut();                   // Fade out the element
    }, fadeOutDelay);
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfvgyhn/L2kvP/) for demo.

Comment: and could you please explain what this does in detail?

Comment: Do you have an example of your current code? You just need to call `onPostAdded` whenever your "post added" event occurs. For example, in the fiddle, onPostAdded is called when you click the "submit" button.

Answer (score 0):

or, easier: http://jsfiddle.net/LekisS/L2kvP/1/

$('div#flash_notice').delay(1000).fadeOut();

Comment: That doesn't reset the timer if the button is clicked multiple times before the fade out occurs. I'm not sure how Justin Meltzer wants it to work though.